# CSS Triangle clip-path with SVG Flag not displaying in Tablet/IPad

Tags: html, css, ipad, svg, tablet

Hi there I have a triangle corner element in my html/css.

The clip path works well on desktop but on Tablet/Ipad this does not work - it just displays normal rectangle flag and doesn't clip

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flag-icon-css/2.8.0/css/flag-icon.min.css" />
```

HTML

```
<div class="triangle"><span class="flag-icon flag-icon-us"></span></div>
```

CSS

```
.triangle {
    position: absolute;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0% 100%, 0 0, 100% 0%);
    clip-path: polygon(0% 100%, 0 0, 100% 0%);
    border-top: 70px solid #d50032;
    border-right: 70px solid transparent;
}
.triangle>span {
    position: relative;
    top: -71px;
    left: -5px;
    background-size: contain;
    background-position: 0%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;   
    font-size: 70px;   
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my answer, did not need to clip it within another div..just all on the one class. Doh!

```
.triangle>span {
    position: absolute;
    top: -12px;
    left: 0;
    background-size: contain;
    background-position: 0%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    -webkit-clip-path: polygon(70% 0, 0 0, 0 70%);
    clip-path: polygon(70% 0, 0 0, 0 70%);
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at https://www.wonderflags.pro/css-shapes it should be (inverted triangle)

```
.triangle {
-webkit-clip-path: polygon(50% 100%, 0 0, 100% 0);
clip-path: polygon(50% 100%, 0 0, 100% 0);
}
```